# Monthly and Yearly growth rate in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df =  pd.DataFrame()

df['A'] = np.linspace(1000, 2000, 120)
df['B'] = np.linspace(1000, 3000, 120)
df['C'] = np.linspace(1000, 4000, 120)
df.index = pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=120, freq='MS', name='Date')
```

I need monthly growth rate referring the corresponding value of the same month of the first year(2012) for each columns as will as yearly Maximum growth rate referring the maximum value of the first year(2012) for each column.
My try is:

```
avg_month_yoy = df.groupby(['month','year',])['A'].apply(  lambda v: 
v.sub(v.shift(1)).div(v.shift(1)).multiply(100).mean()
).reset_index()
```

I got the following output:

```
     month  year   A
0    April  2012 NaN
1    April  2013 NaN
2    April  2014 NaN
3    April  2015 NaN
4    April  2016 NaN
5    April  2017 NaN
6    April  2018 NaN
7    April  2019 NaN
8    April  2020 NaN
9    April  2021 NaN
10  August  2012 NaN
11  August  2013 NaN
12  August  2014 NaN
13  August  2015 NaN
14  August  2016
```

My expected output of monthly growth rate dataframe:

```
date                          A                    B                                      --- year   month        
01-01-2012    (Xa@Jan2012-Xa@Jan2012)/Xa@Jan2012 (Xb@Jan2012-Xb@Jan2012)/Xb@Jan2012   ---  2012    Jan   
01-02-2012    (Xa@Feb2012-Xa@Feb2012)/Xa@Feb2012   (Xb@Feb2012-Xb@Feb2012)/Xb@Feb2012   --- 2012    Feb                         
            ...      ....     ....       ....       ....     ....
01-12-2022    (Xa@Dec2022-Xa@Dec2012)/Xa@Dec2012   (Xb@Dec2022-Xb@Dec2012)/Xb@Dec2012   ---  2012    Dec
```

My expected output of yearly growth rate dataframe:

```
year      A                                 B                                              C        
   
2012 (Max.Xa@2012-Max.Xa@2012)/Max.Xa@2012 (Max.Xb@2012-Max.Xb@2012)/Max.Xb@2012    (Max.Xc@2012-Max.Xc@2012)/Max.Xc@2012   
2013 (Max.Xa@2013-Max.Xa@2012)/Max.Xa@2012 (Max.Xb@2013-Max.Xb@2012)/Max.Xb@2012    (Max.Xc@2013-Max.Xc@2012)/Max.Xc@2012
 ...     ...                       ...                     ...
2022 (Max.Xa@2022-Max.Xa@2012)/Max.Xa@2012 (Max.Xb@2022-Max.Xb@2012)/Max.Xb@2012    (Max.Xc@2022-Max.Xc@2012)/Max.Xc@2012
```

Comment: Please add your expected results, after reading [mre]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the right formula of monthly and yearly growth rate so I rewrite my question

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `df.pct_change(12)` and `df.groupby(df.index.year).max().pct_change()`?

Comment: Thanks, @Timus . I am looking for yearly percentage change of each column referring the maximum value of the first year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo : https://trinket.io/python3/fa778eb76d?showInstructions=true

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df =  pd.DataFrame()

df['A'] = np.linspace(1000, 2000, 120)
df['B'] = np.linspace(1000, 3000, 120)
df.index = pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=120, freq='MS', name='Date')


# Monthly dataframe:
# - append to index for Month
df_m = df.copy(deep=False)
df_m['Month'] = df.index.month
df_m = df_m.set_index('Month', append=True)

# First year's worth of monthly data:
# - first 12 rows, indexed only by Month
df_f = df_m.droplevel('Date', axis=0).iloc[0:12]

# Divide monthly data by first year's data (implicitly joined on common index: Month)
print((df_m / df_f - 1) * 100)



# Yearly dataframe:
# - max of each column per year
df_y = df.groupby(df.index.year).max()

# Divide yearly data by first row from yearly data
print((df_y / df_y.iloc[0] - 1) * 100)
```

Comment: So thanks,@MatBailie, I got what I want using your code

Answer (score 0):

A little confused on what your intended output is, but could you not do something like so:

```
df['a_yoy'] = df['A'].pct_change(12) * 100
df['a_m_growth'] = ((df['A']/df['A'].shift(1)) -1) * 100
```

Or do you need the output a different way? Drop a comment and I can tweak this

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is ambiguous.
You can create one dataframe for each case (months and years)

```
df['month'] = df.index.month
df["year"] = df.index.year

df_month = df.copy()
df_year = df[df.month == 1].copy()

for col in ["A", "B", "C"]:
    df_month[col] = (df_month[col] / df_month[col].shift(1) - 1) *100
    df_year[col] = (df_year[col] / df_year[col].shift(1) - 1) *100
```

Outputs (you can format as you please then):

[image]

Comment: I need, @snowman,  monthly growth rate referring the month at which the maximum value is take place every year for each columns  as will as yearly growth rate referring the maximum value of the first year(2012) for each column.

Comment: Please ,@snowman, I rephrase my question and I badly need your help